# How to change the delimiter that Jersey EventInput uses

Tags: java, jersey, server-sent-events, eventsource

I need to subscribe for SSE (Server Sent Events). I know that the standard says the delimiter between the events is supposed to be "\r\n\r\n" - check "end-of-line" in the grammar here:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#parsing-an-event-stream

but the stream that I'm supposed to consume does not follow the standard and delimits with '\n'.

I decided to make alternative implementation of the Jersey EventInput class which you can see here:

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/12e5d8bdf22bcd2676a1032ed69473cf2bbc48c7/media/sse/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/EventInput.java

So my implementation would duplicate the EventInput with the only difference - the delimiters specified. It looks something like:

```
public class MyEventInput extends ChunkedInput<InboundEvent> {
/**
 * SSE event chunk parser - SSE chunks are delimited with a fixed "\n" and "\r\n\r\n" delimiter in the response stream.
 */
private static final ChunkParser SSE_EVENT_PARSER = ChunkedInput.createMultiParser("\n", "\r\n\r\n");
```

The compiler totally accepts my implementation, but when I try to run it, it doesn't work! It hangs in the following line:

```
final MyEventInput eventInput = target.register(SseFeature.class)
                                .request().get(MyEventInput.class);
```

While if I do the following it works without problem:

```
final EventInput eventInput = target.register(SseFeature.class)
                                .request().get(EventInput.class);
```

I started debugging and found out that Jersey uses a class called MessageBodyFactory which does checks like:

```
if (isCompatible(model, c, mediaType))
```

and

`if (model.isReadable(c, t, as, mediaType))`

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/12e5d8bdf22bcd2676a1032ed69473cf2bbc48c7/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/MessageBodyFactory.java#L685

where they check if your class is a valid reader. The valid readers, are obtained (at least to me seemed to, while debugging ... ) with:

```
final Set<MessageBodyReader> customMbrs = Providers.getCustomProviders(injectionManager, MessageBodyReader.class);
final Set<MessageBodyReader> mbrs = Providers.getProviders(injectionManager, MessageBodyReader.class);
```

So my question is ... how can I register MyEventInput as a valid reader so I can use it to subscribe for SSE stream that separates with custom delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since I didn't find another solution, I just "cracked" the Jersey library with reflection and specified different parser for the EventInput class. Here is how I do that(You have to redefine the SSE_EVENT_PARSER field before you instantiate your EventInput ...):

```
Field f = EventInput.class.getDeclaredField("SSE_EVENT_PARSER");
f.setAccessible(true);

Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(f, f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

f.set(null, ChunkedInput.createMultiParser("\n", "\r\n\r\n"));

final EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
```